# Error on the for loop - trying to use loop to count the repetition of letter

Tags: java, string, compiler-errors, applet

On the for loop I have the Java applet is showing me that I have an error. I am trying to use the for loop to count the repetition of letter.

```
String countString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
// at the line below, my java applet says I have an error, and that the 
//"letterCounts" should be a int and not a string, but I need it to be a string
     String n = letterCounts[i];
     if (n.equals("0")) {
          countString = countString + "   ";
     } else if (n.length() == 1) {
          countString = countString + " " + n + " ";
     } else {
          countString = countString + n + " ";
     }
} 
this.countLabel.setText(countString);
```

Comment: This is not JS, and Java and JS are as identical as a car and a cartoon

Comment: -_- didn't realize had tagged them both

Comment: can you give definition of letterCounts ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Would also be useful to know what error you're receiving - please put it in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You donot show the definition of `letterCounts`, but I bet it is `int[] letterCounts`.

So since `letterCounts` is an array of `int`, you cannot just assign it to a `String`.

Just change `String n` to `int n` and your comparison to `n == 0` and it should work.  See below:

```
    String countString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
      int n = letterCounts[i];

      if (n == 0) {
        countString = countString + "   ";
      } else if (n < 10) {
        countString = countString + " " + n + " ";
      } else {
        countString = countString + n + " ";
      }
    } 

    this.countLabel.setText(countString);
```